# Docker unable to start container process

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have various dockerized projects, running in the WSL and working. Today I created a new one, `docker compose build` runs without errors, `docker compose up -d` gives the following error:

`Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/app/server": stat /app/server: no such file or directory: unknown`

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:1.20-alpine AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM base AS development
# Necessary for working inside the HGV network
COPY fortinet.pem /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/fortinet.crt
RUN update-ca-certificates
# Create external debugger
RUN go install github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv@latest
# Restart server on code change
RUN go install github.com/cespare/reflex@latest
COPY reflex.conf /
ENTRYPOINT ["reflex", "-c", "/reflex.conf"]

FROM base AS go-builder
# Retrieve application dependencies.
# This allows the container build to reuse cached dependencies.
# Expecting to copy go.mod and if present go.sum.
COPY go.* ./
RUN go mod download
# Copy local code to the container image.
COPY . .
# Build the binary.
RUN go build -buildvcs=false -v -o server

FROM alpine:latest
# Copy the binary to the production image from the builder stage.
COPY --from=go-builder /app/server /app/server
# Run the web service on container startup.
CMD ["/app/server"]
```

Output of `docker compose build --no-cache`:

```
[+] Building 29.4s (14/14) FINISHED                                                                                                                                                                                                    
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 32B                                                                                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => => transferring context: 35B                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/alpine:latest                                                                                                                                                                 21.1s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/golang:1.20-alpine                                                                                                                                                            10.9s
 => [base 1/2] FROM docker.io/library/golang:1.20-alpine@sha256:568be9586fcaa9f74fc3b670aff12ec2c1fecc17bccc0b05bd909015045f0f2b                                                                                                  0.0s
 => CACHED [stage-3 1/2] FROM docker.io/library/alpine:latest@sha256:82d1e9d7ed48a7523bdebc18cf6290bdb97b82302a8a9c27d4fe885949ea94d1                                                                                             0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => => transferring context: 17.02kB                                                                                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => CACHED [base 2/2] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => [go-builder 1/4] COPY go.* ./                                                                                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => [go-builder 2/4] RUN go mod download                                                                                                                                                                                          1.8s
 => [go-builder 3/4] COPY . .                                                                                                                                                                                                     0.1s
 => [go-builder 4/4] RUN go build -buildvcs=false -v -o server                                                                                                                                                                    6.1s
 => [stage-3 2/2] COPY --from=go-builder /app/server /app/server                                                                                                                                                                  0.1s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                                                                                            0.1s 
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                                                                           0.1s 
 => => writing image sha256:b54a3f0b99cb50b8787f0f5b11b4e41d932c2a1ae097b8238a577bd4a014471d                                                                                                                                      0.0s 
 => => naming to docker.io/library/app-api-server
```

Any hint?

Comment: What does your `/app/server` file looks like? Also, the error says the `/app/server` is not present. Are you sure your `COPY` command works properly?

Comment: What do you mean with `what does the file looks like`? What and now can I check it? I add the build log.

Comment: Yes, the contents of your `server` is not related to the problem. You could add `RUN ls` right before `CMD /app/server`.  Also, add `RUN ls /app/` after the `RUN go build ...` command. I'm just trying to make sure that the `/app/` folder exists and copied properly.

Comment: I added the `RUN`s, same result, except that I see them in the output logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, I forgot to add the `target: dedvelopment` to the `services:server:build` in the `docker-compose.yaml`.